# How to create a sphere with faces that alternate to create rings of diamonds using instancing?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a diamond-encrusted ball but am struggling to find a sphere mesh that allows me to add diamonds in rings periodically. I am using instancing to place the diamonds around the sphere however the UV layout isn't right. Is there a way to do this in a way similar to this image? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. At first I input a number of how many rows I want on each half sphere, e.g. 36 in my case. Then I multiply it by 2 (for top and bottom) and plug it into the *Count* of a *Points* node.
2. I divide ½ Pi (90°) by the input-1 to get the angle per row from center line to top. The cosine of this angle multiplied by the ID of each point gives the Z position for each point.
3. I instance a *Curve Circle* on each point, the sine of angle × ID is the scale of each circle. I also put some random Z rotation on the instances to vary the placement of their points.
4. Then I delete instances to remove the central rings up to a value of my choice according to their distance from the center line to make room for the golden ring from the reference image (which I did not create in my setup).
5. Then I realized the instances to get rid of the decreasing point radius towards the top and bottom and resample the curves by a value to set the distance between the individual diamonds in a row.
6. I added a diamond object with the *Object Info* node and instance it on the points of the resampled curve.
7. Then I make the diamonds point towards the center with a *Align Euler to Vector* node, to get the right alignment I subtract the position of the points from 0, 0, 0. The *Rotate Euler* node is to randomly rotate the diamonds around their Z axis so that they are not all looking uniform.

[image: geometry nodes setup]

[image]